# SmartGit: How to set base branch when creating new branch?

Tags: git, smartgit

I'm trying to migrate from TortoiseGit to SmartGit.

TG has quite clear interface for creating new brach: [image]

But in SmartGit I've found only "Branch -> Add Branch" which shows quite poor dialog: [image]

I don't want to switch to some base branch every time I want create a new one. Is there a way to choose the base branch in SmartGit like in TG?

Comment: The interface on *Smart*Git looks quite inferior. Why do you want to move to it in the first place? Any compelling reasons?

Comment: I'm just trying something new. Many my colleagues use it. As well after 2 days of using SG I've found it quite handy. In TG I need many right- and left-mouse button clicks when I create/switch/pull/push branches. In SG I can do it a bit faster.

Comment: You should try the command line. It's even faster and more handy although the learning curve is steeper.

Comment: I have some colleagues who still use CLI. I feel sorry for them. CLI can never be faster than good GUI. It's impossible to choose set of files in cli as fast as it's done in gui with clicks, as well as checking modifications in every file as fast as it's done in gui with double-clicks and so on. I really recommend it to you.

Comment: This is an [xkcd:386](http://xkcd.com/386/) moment so I'll pass. The fact that you actually had to ask a question on how to do such a simple operation with the new GUI you're trying out is worth reflecting on.

Comment: SG's **Add Branch** is for the very common use case of creating a branch just from your HEAD. If you want to create a branch on any other commit, just go to the **Log**, select the corresponding commit (you can **Reveal** a branch or tag there, filter for a certain log message, ...) and use **Add Branch** from the context menu there.

Comment: @mstrap, you should add this as an answer as it is the way I do this.

Comment: @WORMSS, thanks for confirming that workflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SmartGit's **Add Branch** command is for the very common use case of creating a branch just from your `HEAD`. If you want to create a branch on any other commit, just go to the **Log**, select the corresponding commit (you can **Reveal** a branch or tag there, use **Edit|Filter Commits** to filter for a certain log message, ...) and use **Add Branch** from the context menu.

Comment: This is the way. But actually it's not so fast and handy anyway. Nevertheless thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 5):

You can use command line for this purpose:

```
git branch <new branch name> <the branch name from which it was created>
```

for example

```
git branch test2 test1
```

will create a branch `test2` which is base on `test1`

Comment: no thanx. I'm looking for fast and handy method. CLI is the last what I'd use :)